# How does the democracy_pallet store a Vec<> in its storage?

Tags: pallet

I learnt that in storage, we can only have a fixed size for data structures, we cannot have a String, an array... So how, in democracy_pallet, they store a Vec<> and not a BoundedVec<> ?

for more precision, they have an enum containing a `Vec<u8>`

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
pub enum PreimageStatus<AccountId, Balance, BlockNumber> {
    /// The preimage is imminently needed at the argument.
    Missing(BlockNumber),
    /// The preimage is available.
    Available {
        data: Vec<u8>, // <-------------- here
        provider: AccountId,
        deposit: Balance,
        since: BlockNumber,
        /// None if it's not imminent.
        expiry: Option<BlockNumber>,
    },
}
```

that is stored in the pallet's storage

```
    #[pallet::storage]
    pub type Preimages<T: Config> = StorageMap<
        _,
        Identity,
        T::Hash,
        PreimageStatus<T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>, T::BlockNumber>,
    >;
```

So how, and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `#[pallet::without_storage_info]` macro to escape the Bounded storage check, and its used by democracy pallet (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6e5ee5155aaf8f9c25a1a2292f73a041ab501ed7/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L250)

Comment: Ooooh i see ! and what are the consequences of using this macro ?

Comment: Its meant to make migration easier since most of the older pallets where written when this check did not exist. The consequence is that if you have no other checks in place, an attacker could store large data and bloat your chain state.

Comment: Okay ! Thank you for the information :)